# Notices.txt or Copyright file header when porting code

Tags: copyright, apache-2.0, derivative-works

The following Java project contains an Apache 2.0 license https://github.com/apache/pdfbox-jbig2/blob/master/LICENSE.txt as well as a copyright header on every file in the project https://github.com/apache/pdfbox-jbig2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/jbig2/Dictionary.java.

If one were to port the code, to for example an Apache 2 licensed golang project, what is necessary to meet the terms of the license? The files aren't being copied 1:1 but are derivative works in my understanding. Which of the following are required?

- Attribute the source project in a NOTICES.txt
- Update the license of the project to include a copy of the license of this project (so 2 licenses stacked on top of each other)
- Add a copyright header to every `.go` file corresponding to a `.java` file in the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the requirements of the license, you may move the Apache 2.0 license into a single license.txt and the notices (attribution) into a single notices.txt for the entire project.

The language...

> Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
> contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file...

... just says it is licensed under Apache, there are no addnl implications for you.

Please consider adding [SPDX identifiers](https://spdx.dev/ids/) to each file. These license identifiers are the state of the art way to support any future automation w.r.t. license compliance.